# How to log a Date property into a database using log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, log4net

may be somebody can help me: I am using log4net for logging and I configured an appender to log to a SQL-Server database. When logging I create my own LoggingEvent object that contains a set of properties I want to log. This LoggingEvent is then given to the logger.

Problem: One of the properties is an object of class CobDate (it encapsulates a certain "close of business" date - for those that might be interested). The only attribute here is a DateTime value.

Now, I know how to retrieve a property from the logging event and pass it as parameter to the INSERT commandText:

```
  <parameter>      
      <parameterName value="@cob"/>
      <dbType value="Date"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
        <key value="COB_DATE" />
      </layout>          
  </parameter>
```

But this fails with error "Parametervalue could not be converted from CobDate into DateTime".. So I assume some conversion method is missing in my own created CobDate class? Which one?

On the other hand I know how to pass a date into the insert command:

```
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@timestamp"/>
    <dbType value="DateTime"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
  </parameter>
```

but this is only the current datetime as a timestamp - not the CobDate property I want to use...

=> What can I do? Is there i certain method I must override in my new CobDate class?

Comment: Ok, found a "solution": Instead of putting the new CobDate object into the properties set I put the inne DateTime attribute into it. This can then be picked up as shown in the first parameter section via a property.

Comment: And I think this works due to the fact the DateTime already implements the IConvertible interface that is used (I got a InvalidClassCastException when picking the new CobDate object as a property)